# Issue with opacity rendering with gsap animation on SVG

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, opacity, gsap

I've got an issue with this website : http://nousprochesaidants.com/#carte

The website is built mainly with SVG and animated with the GSAP library.

For some reasons, I've got some rendering issues on chrome, even the latest version.

You can see an image example here : https://thomas-dev.com/images/opacity-nok.jpg

As you can see on triangles on background, opacity is not properly rendered on the left, but well rendered on the right side...

Chrome seems to not render opacity attributes on some computers, as if it needs more memory/cpu to do that...

How can I debug it, and do you have any idea of what happen here ?

Thank you !

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.  We can't reasonably debug your website for you.

Comment: Yeah I understand... The thing is I don't even know what to show you... The tween animation seems to work (zoom out of the map when you click on a state), and the opacity is 0 on the CSS, but it's still visible...

Comment: Seems to work on chrome 73, not 74...

Comment: if you've found a bug in Chrome, [report it here](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick workaround:  Remove the `will-change: opacity;` from `#app #particles-js {}`.

---

I wish I could reproduce this in a small static example.  But it is resisting me.  There must be another factor at play, perhaps script related, that is triggering the bug.

I am sure the Chrome folks would appreciate it if you could post a copy of the broken version your site somewhere. Then file a bug for them at http://crbug.com.

Comment: Thank you ! Yes I will post this website under a subdomain with the issue for chrome team and I will report it. There is a lot of libraries and scripts on this website, hard to spot the issue sometimes...

Comment: Thanks. Please post the bug link here, for future reference.

Comment: I reported it and installed a copy if the broken website here : http://nousprochesaidants.com/broken/#carte

Comment: And this is the bug link : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=971558